# C: strtok on pointer inside a struct

Tags: c

I have struct with this definition:

```
typedef struct gRow{
    char *txt;
    char *fileName;
    int line;
} gRow;
```

and i want to use strtok on the txt string. so, in some function that has `gRow *row`, i do this:

```
strtok(row->txt, SEPERATOR_CHARACTERS);
```

and this is the point where i get Segmentation Fault. if i replace it with:

```
strtok(strdup(row->txt), SEPERATOR_CHARACTERS);
```

it works just fine. any ideas why?

Thanks.

Shahar.

Comment: Do you initialize `row->txt` properly before the call to `strtok`?

Comment: Don't forget to free the memory allocated with strdup after you have finished with it!

Comment: Peter, I did. Jackson, Thanks, I know I should free it - but i hope to find solution that won't requires using strdup.

Comment: Code sample is incomplete. Please show how `row` is initialized.

Answer (score 3):

Note that strtok modifies the string - if your txt pointer is pointing at a read-only string (e.g. a const string literal) then you will get an exception.

Answer (score 1):

You need to allocate the memory for gRow *row ; 
Then it will work fine, I hope.

Comment: I did allocate... the code here is from function that get the pointer after everything already allocated.

Answer (score 1):

`strtok` modifies the string given to it. If you don't have the right to modify it, you might get a Segmentation Fault. `strdup` prevents that by copying the string.

Answer (score 1):

[**strtok**](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strtok/) modifies its first argument.

In case 1 looks like you were passing a pointer to char constant which could not be modified.

and in case 2 you were passing a modifiable copy of it returned by [**strdup**](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strdup.html).

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
in case 1, this char pointer isn't constant (i didn't defined it as one). so... what makes it happens?

Comment: @Shaharg: I meant, did you do something like: row->txt = "text"; If yes then you cannot modify what row->txt is pointing to, so you cannot pass row->txt to strtok.